# Reattach to lost X11 session

Tags: x11

I'm using X11 forwarding over `ssh` to run Linux apps on my Windows box, and when the network drops it loses everything that was running. Is there anything similar to `screen` for X11?

Comment: Clarify. Why not just use `screen`? Or `XVNC`? You run screen on the Linux machine and when your network drops, reconnect and use `screen -DR` to reattach the session.

Comment: @nix Will that work for X apps?

Comment: @nix I don't think `screen` works for gui apps.

Comment: Of course, screen would require running from an xterm.

Answer (score 42):

[Xpra](http://code.google.com/p/partiwm/wiki/xpra) or the [Xpra fork](http://xpra.org/) claim to be exactly that:

> So basically it's [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) for remote X apps.

I haven't used it in a while, but it worked pretty well when I tried it. You start the server on the remote machine:

```
[remote] $ xpra start :13
```

Then you attach to the server from your local machine:

```
[local] $ xpra attach ssh:remote:13
```

And now anything displayed on X display 13 on the remote machine will appear locally:

```
[remote] $ DISPLAY=:13 xeyes
```

Comment: There's also [WinSwitch](http://winswitch.org/), which at a glance looks like it integrates xpra and other related software.

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing). The principle somewhat is similar to screen: you run a VNC server (the backgound `SCREEN` process), and a VNC client (the foreground `screen` process). The VNC server is an X server, so you can run X applications in it.

Run a VNC server on the Linux box and a client on the Windows box. You have several implementations to choose from; one possibility is [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/). TightVNC is in many Linux distributions (if it's not in yours, either install it or pick a different implementation), and there's a Windows client.

If your two machines aren't very close on the network — if there's a firewall or a risk of an eavesdropper between them — you'll need to tunnel the VNC traffic through ssh. Have ssh forward the local port 5900 to the remote port 5900 (5900 corresponds to the display `:0`, use 5901 for `:1`, etc.).

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you can forward X into `screen`.  Only thing to do is to set up the `$DISPLAY` in the `screen` window so that it is the same out side of it.

#### Procedure

after `ssh -X` into the remote machine, type

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
```

and copy the result, usually `localhost:N.0`. Then enter `screen`, in the local `screen` window,

```
$ export DISPLAY=localhost:N.0
```

After this, run any `X` required program within the screen window will do.

**NOTE:** for each `screen` window, the environment variables are independent. So for each window, you might need to set it up separately.

#### References

- [X11 Forwarding over Gnu Screen, is it possible?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9920/x11-forwarding-over-gnu-screen-is-it-possible)

Comment: Hi Chong, welcome to unix.SE.  Since the details of the solution you link are simple, it's better to re-write them explicitly here.  This way the answer is preserved should something happen to the post on askubuntu.com.  Of course, it's a good idea to keep the link present as well because it helps to source your material.

Comment: I tried this solution, but I cannot close my ssh session without killing the running X application.  This somehow defeats the purpose of it...  How should I disconnect from the remote host leaving the remote application running?

Answer (score 1):

I found [X2Go](https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/start) to be very good at this. It creates separate windows like X11 does (Single application mode), and the latency is much better than xpra, which I found to be unusable.