# Detach/reattach an application run on X over SSH?

Tags: ssh, x11, gui

I have a development server that I leave running all the time, and a development laptop that I turn off/on everyday.

I have a GUI application on the server that I'd like to run over SSH -X, and I'd like to leave it running even when my dev laptop is powered off.

Is there a way to detach and then re-attach to that application over SSH -X?

I'd prefer not to use VNC in my case.

Comment: See also [GNU Screen for X11 Forwarding](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10597/gnu-screen-for-x11-forwarding)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Xmove](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xmove) should be able to do what you want.

Here is a [howto](http://www.dreness.com/blog/?p=35) (dated 2006).

Comment: Xmove has been abandoned a long time ago and it is hard to get running these days.

Answer (score 12):

There's [xpra](http://code.google.com/p/partiwm/wiki/xpra) (or a newer [fork](http://xpra.org/)), a slightly more recent tool than xmove.

Comment: xpra is also called *screen for X*, which describes well what it does and is available on all the usual platforms.

Comment: Thnx!. As mentioned: "..."screen for X", ... you probably want to instead check out the fork at http://xpra.org"