# How can I achieve the effect of MS remote desktop on Linux?

Tags: xorg, remote, remote-desktop, freerdp

On Windows machines, if one machine A runs the remote desktop service, and another machine B (which in fact doesn't have to be Windows) runs a remote desktop client - then the user on B can 'steal' control of the session on A, see the app windows which were opened there and interact with them. Note that RDP also allows you to open a new session if there's no existing one, but that's not what the question is about.

My question: How can I achieve the same with A being a Linux machine, running an X server with an X session in progress.

**Notes:**

- A solution need not be based on MSRDP itself, it could be NX, or VNC, or whatever else you like.
- I'm willing to install software on A and on B, including installation as the root user.
- Commercial solutions are relevant, though I would rather not resort to them.
- Solution may involve opening additional ports on A (in addition to, say, port 22 for SSH).
- Assume the distributions are Debian-based and fairly recent.
- This question is similar to [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55310/how-to-attach-to-remote-machines-local-display-session-over-ssh), but it's not the same, since : 1. I'm willing to run services other than just X and 2. In that question, the OP seems more interested in getting specific windows, while for me it's important to see the whole thing.
- Solutions in which both the users on A and B can interact with the same session are also relevant.

Comment: install vnc-server on machine A and instal vnc viewer on machine B.

Comment: @MelBurslan: My limited experience with vnc is that I can use it to start a new X session on A from B, not to connect to an existing one. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: It has been discussed before: http://serverfault.com/questions/27044/how-to-vnc-into-an-existing-x-session

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To take control of a running X session you will need to configure your VNC server to connect to the same display as X.  Generally, X will be connected to the first display - `:0`.

You will also need the X Authority for that X session.  This can be found by accessing the X Authority file that the remote Display Manager is using.  This depends on your Display Manager and can be found using `ps aux` and `grep`.  For example: `psaux | grep Xorg` gives you something similar to:

```
/usr/libexec/Xorg -background none :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -listen tcp vt1 -noswitch
```

Note the `-auth` option as you'll need it with VNC. You then need to run something like the following as `root` on the remote computer after installing `x11vnc`:

```
/usr/bin/x11vnc -norc -forever -shared -bg -autoport 5900 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
```

The easiest way would be to create a service that runs this for you on boot. On distros that use `systemd`, create a file `/etc/systemd/system/x11vnc.service` similar to the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=VNC Server for X11
Requires=display-manager.service
After=display-manager.service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -norc -forever -shared -bg \
        -autoport 5900 \
        -rfbauth /etc/x11vnc.pass \
        -o /var/log/x11vnc.log \
        -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Note the `-rfbauth` option. You'll need to create the password file beforehand using:

```
$ sudo x11vnc -storepasswd /etc/x11vnc.pass
```

Alternatively, if you don't feel you need password protected VNC sessions, then simply remove the `-rfbauth` line.

Enable at boot with:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable x11vnc.service
```

Start it manually with:

```
$ sudo systemctl start x11vnc.service
```

You can now connect to the remote computer with your VNC client and take over the session.

Comment: This seems to work, at least in the no-password mode. Now I'll try it with a password set. Also, the VNC server makes numerous suggestions about which options and settings to use; if you have any thoughts on good defaults you could add here, that would be nice (although you've got your +1...).

Comment: I run the above command as a service using `systemd`, with options for password (`-rfbauth`) and a log file  (`-o`).  Nothing more.

Comment: Then maybe you should consider the -ncache option. Anyway, thanks.