# Is possible to change X server without kill client?

Tags: xorg, x11, display

My usecase:
User opertes on `Server1` station. He can use ssh or whatever to connect with `Remote Station` and start some application on it and display it on his station (`Server1`). Now user has to change his place and operate on `Server2`. I know that he can start new instance of application and display it on `Server2`. But I want to dispaly the same running instane of application on `Server2`. Is it possible? How to do that?
[image]

Comment: How does the user connect to `Server 1` in the first place? `ssh -Y`, `vnc`, `nx`?

Comment: Also, what to you mean by "*change his place*". Does he physically need to relocate? Or does he remain at `X CLIENT`?

Comment: @Sebastian User physically sitting at the `Server1` I named it `Server1` because it is `X server`."Change his place" means he physsicaly need to relocate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can reattach if the application has already been started in `X`.

But maybe the following questions help?

### xpra

> [Detach/reattach an application run on X over SSH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11623/detach-reattach-an-application-run-on-x-over-ssh11)
>
> [Reattach to lost X11 session](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10597/gnu-screen-for-x11-forwarding)

Also, `VNC` could be a solution for you. But all these applications require that you restart the gui application on `Server1`