# X11 unable to open display after re-logging into a tmux session

Tags: linux, x11, tmux, xforwarding

I have a desktop at work that I use as a "tmux server."  I `ssh -Y u@Work_Desktop` from home into the Work Desktop then `ssh -Y u@Work_Server` into another server at work.  I run x applications like `gv` and they work OK.

The connection looks like this:  Home PC -> Work Desktop -> Work Server

My tmux on the Work Desktop contains many windows with ssh sessions into Work Server and other work resources.

At the end of the day, I detach from the tmux session using `ctrl-B d` and log out of the Work Desktop.

The next day, I log into the Work Desktop and run `tmux attach`.  But now x no longer works and gv reports

> Unable to open the display

and

> wrong authentication

To fix this, I make a new tmux window and log into Work Server and `echo $DISPLAY`.  I take the DISPLAY from the new tmux window and go to my original tmux window and use `export DISPLAY=DISPLAY_from_aforementioned_echo`.  Now X works OK again, until I log back in the next morning and have to repeat this.

My question is, is there a way to avoid having to reset my DISPLAY setting like this every time I re-login into my Work Desktop?

I have tried the following in my `.tmux.conf` (with and without DISPLAY), to no avail.

`set-option -g update-environment "SSH_ASKPASS SSH_AUTH_SOCK SSH_AGENT_PID SSH_CONNECTION WINDOWID XAUTHORITY DISPLAY"`

Comment: duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10597/reattach-to-lost-x11-session

Comment: This is a completely different question from the one linked as duplicate.

Comment: This helped me: https://goosebearingbashshell.github.io/2017/12/07/reset-display-variable-in-tmux.html