# how to get access again to job running on remote server

Tags: tmux, gvim

I am running jobs on a remote server, using a bad connection which drops frequently. So I use **tmux**, to connect to the session again by re-connecting. This way, I can access my existing terminals, and any jobs that are running on the terminals, eg **vim**.

But if I am running a job like **gvim**, or any other application which opens up a different window, I dont see that window after re-connecting. But I can see the process for it still running using **ps**.

So, after reconnecting, how do I get that gvim window back again for usage?

Comment: On both hosts (the local and the remote), what is the output of `echo $DISPLAY`?

Comment: on server(ubuntu): localhost:11.0
on local(macos): /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.QiYkgwEy87/org.macosforge.xquartz:0

Comment: how does that information help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reattach to lost X11 session](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10597/reattach-to-lost-x11-session) -- While an old question, the answer seems to be pretty much the same today -- Xpra.